# Simple Ajax Post not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an incredibly simple Ajax post which isn't working:

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

            var deviceDetails = [];

            deviceDetails.project_title = 'project';
            //deviceDetails.platform = window.device.platform;
            deviceDetails.platform = 'ios';

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://someserver.com/device_api",
                type: "post",
                data: deviceDetails,
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");

                },
                error:   function(model, xhr, options){
                    alert('failed');

                    console.log('response is : ');
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                },
            });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The server simply does this:

I can see in the network tab of Chrome that the status of the Post is "cancelled". What am i missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is an options request sent?

Comment: I [tried your code](http://jsfiddle.net/75vYt/) and can see that the POST request **is** sent.

Comment: @Quentin I have a logger on the server and it's not being hit. The status of the POST is "cancelled"

Comment: @RahulDesai When i do console.log(xhr); it simple prints "error", nothing else. In the Network tab of Chrome, the Status is "cancelled"

Answer (score 2):

The POST request was being sent, but it wasn't hitting my logger on the server. I changed the url to:

```
url: "http://push.schoolspace.ie/device_api/"
```

with a "/" on the end, and this worked. I think it's to do with the .htaccess file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're suffering from the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of ajax requests. From the documentation for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Comment: Isn't that just for GET requests though and not POST?

Comment: Its not method-specific. I suggest you try an ajax request to your own server. If that works, this is the issue. If that also doesnt its a different one

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            var deviceDetails = [];

            deviceDetails.project_title = 'project';
            //deviceDetails.platform = window.device.platform;
            deviceDetails.platform = 'ios';

            var deviceDetailsObject = JSON.stringify(deviceDetails);

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://push.schoolspace.ie/device_api",
                type: "post",
                data: deviceDetailsObject,
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");

                },
                error:   function(model, xhr, options){
                    alert('failed');

                    console.log('response is : ');
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                },
            });
})
</script>
```

You need to convert the array to a JSON object / string ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ ). The JSON.stringify() function does this for you.